# How to change the direction of a Scaffold's Drawer open animation?

Tags: flutter

The default drawer in a Scaffold opens from left to right, is it possible to change the direction so it opens from the bottom up?

Comment: read this ===>https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_drawer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188895/how-to-implement-a-bottom-navigation-drawer-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  SlideRightRoute({this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(animation),
                child: child,
              ),
        );
}
```

-> You have to use this.

Slide Transition

We will extend the PageRouteBuilder and define the transition builder which will return SlideTransition widget. The SlideTransition widget takes the position of type Animation. We will use Tween to give begin and end offset.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIbTa.gif)

[For More Information](https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823)