# Flutter Minimise container to see what's behind

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need some help with displaying a container above the navbar that you can minimise and see the map behind. [image]

As you can see in this picture, the expanded container sits above the bottom buttons, which are the bottomNavigation of the page. How can I make such a container that when you minimise, you can still see the small line above the buttons to expand it back. Also, once the container is close, you can see map behind.

I am thinking of something like a bottom modal sheet but that shoots up from the bottom of the page, over the buttons. Also the modal bottom shit doesn't minimise to only see the top all times.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: You can use `Drawer` or `BottomSheet` to achieve the desired behaviour. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188895/how-to-implement-a-bottom-navigation-drawer-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here Source Code Link](https://github.com/mrasityilmaz/stackoverflow_answers/blob/main/lib/src/show_bottom_sheet_view/show_modal_bottom_sheet_with_scaffold_view.dart)

`Source Code`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final class ShowModalBottomSheetWithScaffoldView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowModalBottomSheetWithScaffoldView({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShowModalBottomSheetWithScaffoldView> createState() => _ShowModalBottomSheetWithScaffoldViewState();
}

class _ShowModalBottomSheetWithScaffoldViewState extends State<ShowModalBottomSheetWithScaffoldView> {
  late final DraggableScrollableController _draggableScrollableController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _draggableScrollableController = DraggableScrollableController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _draggableScrollableController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        bottomSheetTheme: const BottomSheetThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavBar(draggableScrollableController: _draggableScrollableController),
        bottomSheet: _BottomSheetWidget(draggableScrollableController: _draggableScrollableController),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final DraggableScrollableController draggableScrollableController;
  const _BottomNavBar({
    super.key,
    required this.draggableScrollableController,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            const Divider(),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: _BottomButton(
                    text: "Close Sheet",
                    onPressed: () {
                      draggableScrollableController.animateTo(0, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                    },
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Expanded(
                  child: _BottomButton(
                    text: "Open Sheet",
                    onPressed: () {
                      draggableScrollableController.animateTo(1, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                    },
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ]),
        ));
  }
}

class _BottomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final Color color;
  final Color textColor;

  const _BottomButton({required this.text, required this.onPressed, this.color = Colors.deepOrange, this.textColor = Colors.black});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: color,
          elevation: 0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
          maximumSize: const Size(double.maxFinite, kMinInteractiveDimension * .9),
          fixedSize: const Size(double.maxFinite, kMinInteractiveDimension * .9),
          minimumSize: const Size(double.maxFinite, kMinInteractiveDimension * .9),
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
        ));
  }
}

class _BottomSheetWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final DraggableScrollableController draggableScrollableController;
  const _BottomSheetWidget({super.key, required this.draggableScrollableController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(12)), color: Colors.white),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4), width: 32, height: 4, decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
          Flexible(
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              controller: draggableScrollableController,
              expand: false,
              initialChildSize: .0,
              maxChildSize: .6,
              minChildSize: .0,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item $index")), controller: scrollController, itemCount: 100)),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]